# Reading Visual Foxpro Data From Java using ODBC

Tags: java, jdbc, odbc, visual-foxpro, jdbc-odbc

I am trying to query a dbf table from my Java application. I put in reference this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4818023/reading-a-foxpro-2-6-data-with-java)

I created a system data source using the ODBC Data Source Administrator, I set the data source name to be VFPDS and set the database type to .DBC finaly i set the path to the .dbc file.

the following is my java code:

```
import javax.swing.* ;
import java.awt.* ;
import java.awt.event.* ;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.SQLWarning;
import java.sql.Statement;
// Import custom library containing myRadioListener
import java.sql.DriverManager;

public class testodbc {

public static void main( String args[] )
{
    try
    {
        // Load the database driver
        Class.forName( "sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver" ) ;

        // Get a connection to the database
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection( "jdbc:odbc:VFPDS" ) ;

        // Print all warnings
        for( SQLWarning warn = conn.getWarnings(); warn != null; warn = warn.getNextWarning() )
        {
            System.out.println( "SQL Warning:" ) ;
            System.out.println( "State  : " + warn.getSQLState()  ) ;
            System.out.println( "Message: " + warn.getMessage()   ) ;
            System.out.println( "Error  : " + warn.getErrorCode() ) ;
        }

        // Get a statement from the connection
        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement() ;

        // Execute the query
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery( "SELECT * FROM pmsquoteh" ) ;//code crashes here

        // Loop through the result set
        while( rs.next() )
            System.out.println( rs.getString(1) ) ;

        // Close the result set, statement and the connection
        rs.close() ;
        stmt.close() ;
        conn.close() ;
    }
    catch( SQLException se )
    {   se.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println( "SQL Exception:" ) ;

        // Loop through the SQL Exceptions
        while( se != null )
        {   se.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println( "State  : " + se.getSQLState()  ) ;
            System.out.println( "Message: " + se.getMessage()   ) ;
            System.out.println( "Error  : " + se.getErrorCode() ) ;

            se = se.getNextException() ;
        }
    }
    catch( Exception e )
    {
        System.out.println( e ) ;
    }
}
}
```

I got this exception :

```
java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Visual FoxPro Driver]Not a table.
at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.createSQLException(Unknown Source)
at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.standardError(Unknown Source)
at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.SQLExecDirect(Unknown Source)
at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcStatement.execute(Unknown Source)
at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcStatement.executeQuery(Unknown Source)
at UsingButtons.main(testodbc.java:38)

SQL Exception:
State  : S0002
Message: [Microsoft][ODBC Visual FoxPro Driver]Not a table.
Error  : 123
```

I am sure that the table pmsquoteh exits in the database and my machine is a 64 bit machine.
What am i doing wrong ? I would appreciate specific answers.

Comment: The VFP error "Not a table" can mean a lot of different things. It could mean the table is corrupted. It could also mean that the table has been encrypted. Do you have a copy of VFP available? If so, can you open the table there? If so, you know the problem is with your connecting code. If not, it's the table.

Comment: @TamarE.Granor, I can open the table and see the records in it. so its not the table

Answer (score 0):

I was able to access a FoxPro table with the jdbc-odbc bridge on Windows 7 but it took a number of steps.  I already had the VFP driver installed, and I don't remember where I downloaded it from, so I don't have a link for that.

I copied the code from a jbdc:odbc example here: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Database-SQL-JDBC/SimpleexampleofJDBCODBCfunctionality.htm.

The DriverManager.getConnection method takes a database URL.  To create a URL you need to use the ODBC manager.  Unfortunately for me, the ODBC manager that I could get to through the control panel only worked for 64 bit data sources.  I am not aware of a 64 bit foxpro driver.

To generate a 32 bit DSN you need to run the 32 bit ODBC manager: odbcad32.exe.  My machine had several copies.  I ran the one from C:\Windows\SysWOW64.  Go to the System DSN tab and select the Microsoft Visual Foxpro Driver.  When you click finish, you will get a dialog that asks for a Data Source Name, description and path to the FoxPro database or tables.  You also have to specify whether you want to connect to a .dbc or a free table directory.  Your error message makes me wonder if you had the wrong option selected on your DSN.

The database URL I passed in to the getConnection method was "jdbc:odbc:mydsnname".

After I ran this, I received an error:

> [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] The specified DSN contains an
>   architecture mismatch between the Driver and Application

This was because I was using a 64 bit JVM with a 32 bit DSN. I downloaded a 32 bit JVM and was able to use it to run my sample class.

I do not know if there is a switch you can set on a 64 bit JVM to tell it to run as 32 bit.

Answer (score 0):

I used the JDBC driver from here:

http://www.csv-jdbc.com/relational-junction/jdbc-database-drivers-products/new-relational-junction-dbf-jdbc-driver/

Works fine for me. In testing so far (about an hour), it reads MEMO files and seems to have had no issues with either DBC-containted tables or free DBFs.

Not sure how much this driver costs. The client will only probably pay $100 max since VFP is beyond obsolete.

Answer (score 0):

I am using javadbf-0.4.0.jar for last six month without and problem.I will post my Java class and main program.

```
package foxtablereader.src;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import sun.jdbc.rowset.CachedRowSet;

/**
 *
 * @author kalimk
 */
public class DbfMain {

    static CachedRowSet crs;

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {

       
        DbfConnection foxconn = new DbfConnection();
        Connection connection = null;
                
        String inputTablePath = "c:\\vfp_table\\";
        connection = foxconn.connection(inputTablePath);

        String query = "SELECT * FROM TrigExport2.dbf ";

        crs = foxconn.select(query, connection);
        //crs = ft.query(query, inputTablePath);
        System.out.println(" Size " + crs.size());
        while (crs.next()) {
            System.out.println("DESC " + crs.getString("Serialnum") + " " + crs.getString("cmailcode"));
        }

        inputTablePath = "C:\\sourcecode\\FoxTableReader\\";
        connection = foxconn.connection(inputTablePath);
        query = "SELECT * FROM TrigExports.dbf ";
        crs = foxconn.select(query, connection);

        System.out.println(" Size " + crs.size());

        int z = 1;
        while (crs.next()) {
            System.out.println(z++ + "  " + crs.getString("Serialnum") + " " + crs.getString("cmailcode"));
        }

        inputTablePath = "C:\\sourcecode\\FoxTableReader\\";
        connection = foxconn.connection(inputTablePath);
        String queryinsert = "insert into Mcdesc (Desc,Mailcode,Del_type,Column1) values ('Kalim','KHAN', 'ERUM','KHAN')";
        foxconn.insertUpdate(queryinsert, connection);

        inputTablePath = "C:\\sourcecode\\FoxTableReader\\";
        connection = foxconn.connection(inputTablePath);
        String queryupdate = "update  Mcdesc set  Column1= 'Sadiqquie'  where Desc = 'Kalim'";
        foxconn.insertUpdate(queryupdate, connection);
    }

}


package foxtablereader.src;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import sun.jdbc.rowset.CachedRowSet;

/**
 *
 * @author kalimk
 */
public class DbfConnection {

    public Connection connection(String inputTablePath) throws SQLException {

        Connection con = null;
        //String jdbURL = "jdbc:DBF:/C:\\vfp_table\\";
        String jdbURL = "jdbc:DBF:/" + inputTablePath;
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.setProperty("delayedClose", "0");

        try {

            Class.forName("com.caigen.sql.dbf.DBFDriver");

            try {

                con = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbURL, props);

            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(DbfConnection.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(DbfConnection.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        return con;
    }

    public CachedRowSet select(String cQuery, Connection con) {
        CachedRowSet crs = null;
        try {

            Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(cQuery);
            crs = new CachedRowSet();
            crs.populate(rs);
            stmt.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return crs;
    }

    public boolean insertUpdate(String cQuery, Connection con) {
        boolean crs = false;
        try {

            PreparedStatement pStmnt = con.prepareStatement(cQuery);
            crs = pStmnt.execute();
            pStmnt.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return crs;
    }

    public int insertUpdateCount(String cQuery, Connection con) {

        int count = 0;
        try {

            Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
            count = stmt.executeUpdate(cQuery);
            System.out.println("Number of rows updated in database =  " + count);
            stmt.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return count;
    }

    public int insertUpdateCount2(String cQuery, Connection con) {

        int count = 0;
        boolean crs = false;
        try {

            PreparedStatement pStmnt = con.prepareStatement(cQuery);
            count = pStmnt.executeUpdate(cQuery);
            pStmnt.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return count;
    }

    public static void DBDisconnect(Connection DBCon) {
        try {

            if (DBCon != null) {
                DBCon.close();
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println(e.toString());
        } finally {
            try {

                DBCon.close();
                //System.err.println("Fimally is always executed");
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(DbfConnection.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: No info on where you got this driver?